# favicon is not displayed on html page

Tags: html, favicon

I want to put icon for the title

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html>
<head><title>TITLE</title></head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="logo.png" />
<body>

</body>
```

index.html and logo.png are in a same folder.

there is no Icon displayed.

Please guide.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Recommend that you turn your "PNG" in "ICO" to end this problem. This site can help. http://www.favicon.cc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a png, try this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/image.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser but favicons generally are heavily cached, above and beyond normal caching. If you've opened the site before, the old icon (or absence of icon) is stored until all data associated with the website is removed completely. Clearing all browsing data should help with the most common browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Details may be found here: **[FAVICONS](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon)**